Covering directions with rational circles
In the usual Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can cover all possible directions with a single circle centered at the origin (in fact, any such circle will do). However, if we somehow decide to pursue geometry not on the Euclidean plane, but rather on the rational plane $\mathbb{Q}^2$, this will no longer work automatically. As an example, the rational unit circle $S^1\cap\mathbb{Q}^2$ has no point in the diagonal direction $\mathbb{Q}\cdot(1,1)$. If, on the other hand, we take our circle to be of radius $\sqrt{2}$ instead, we will hit the direction $\mathbb{Q}\cdot(1,1)$, but no longer have any points on the coordinate axis $\mathbb{Q}\cdot (1,0)$. Taken together, these two circles cover many directions but still miss out on (e.g.) $\mathbb{Q}\cdot (2,1)$. So, the question arises:
Can you cover all rational directions with only finitely many rational circles centered at the origin?
(To be clear about the terminology here:

A rational direction is taken to mean a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{Q}^2$, i.e. a set of the form $\mathbb{Q}\cdot v$ for some nonzero $v\in \mathbb{Q}^2$.

A rational circle centered at the origin is a set of the form $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2: x^2+y^2=r^2\}$ for some real $r>0$.

A circle covers a direction if their intersection is not empty.)


If you're feeling up to it, here is a related bonus question that I don't know the answer to. But beware that the statement will spoil the answer to the original question:

 Can you achieve the same thing with finitely many rational circles that merely don't contain the origin (instead of having to be centered around it)?

Have fun solving this! :)

Base question:

 Covering all rational directions is impossible.

Proof:

 By Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinitely many primes congruent to 1 modulo 4, and by Fermat we know that these are all the sums of two squares. Therefore, each of these primes corresponds to a set of directions.


 For any prime $p = a^2+b^2$, the rational points in its directions have coordinates $(\frac{an}{d},\frac{bn}{d})$ and squared radius $\frac{pn^2}{d^2}$. Since $p$ is the only prime raised to an odd power, no circle covering that radius can cover any other prime, and so infinitely many circles are necessary.


Disclaimer: I misread the question, this is an answer to a different question that what OP asked. The question asked about rational directions only, this answer talks about all real directions.
Bonus question:

 Even with countably infinitely many circles you cannot cover all directions.

The argument is very short but requires slightly more high-powered maths, namely

 different kinds of infinity, countable and uncountable, see for example here

Using this we have

 A rational circle only contains countable many points. A collection of finitely many rational circles or countable many rational circles still contains only countable many points (by Cantor's diagonal argument). The real circle on the other hand contains uncountable many directions.


Not quite! The question is only about rational directions, so countably many circles are plenty sufficient.

@TimSeifert You are correct, my bad for not reading properly. I will put a disclaimer in front that this answers a different question that you actually asked.
